# How to access Props in React child funtion

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to learn a little about React from a tutorial, but having a little trouble access data created in App.js from a child class. Here's App.js:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import './App.css';
import Todos from './components/Todos';

function App() {

  const [state, setState] = useState
  (
    {
      todos: [
        {
        id: 1,
        title: 'Take out the trash',
        completed: false
        },
        {
        id: 2,
        title: 'Dinner with wife',
        completed: false
        },
        {
        id: 3,
        title: 'Meeting with boss',
        completed: false
        },
        ]

    }

    );

  console.log(state.todos)
  return (
    <div className="App">
    <Todos todos={state.todos}/>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Here's the child class:

```
 import React from 'react';
 function Todos() {
      //console.log(props.todos)
      return (
        <div>
        <h1>Todos</h1>
        </div>
      );
    }

    export default Todos;
```

When I try to write the todos array to the console, it gives the message:

```
./src/components/Todos.js
  Line 4:  'props' is not defined  no-undef
```

How would one access these properties? It looks like they are defined under "Props" according to the React Chrome add-on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Child component receives `props` as an argument.

```
 import React from 'react';

 function Todos(props) {
      console.log(props.todos)
      return (
        <div>
        <h1>Todos</h1>
        </div>
      );
    }

 export default Todos;
```

And with ES6 you can destructure these `props` inside the arguments as well.

```
 import React from 'react';

 function Todos({ todos }) {
      console.log(todos)
      return (
        <div>
        <h1>Todos</h1>
        </div>
      );
    }

 export default Todos;
```

See sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/affectionate-wilbur-15nd2